# Nesting WCF data contracts with lists

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have set up my WCF service as follows:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface MyInterface

 <OperationContract()>
 Function Search(ByVal parm1As String, ByVal parm2 As String, ByVal parm3 As String) As MyResponse

End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class MyResponse

<DataMember()>
Public Property SearchResult() As SearchRes

<DataMember()>
Public Property RecordInfo() As List(Of RecordInf)

<DataContract()>
Public Class SearchRes
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop1() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop2() As Integer

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop3() As String
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class RecordInf
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop4() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop5() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop6() As List(Of MyList)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop7() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop8() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop9() As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop10() As String
End Class

<DataContract()>
Public Class Contr
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Prop11() As String
End Class
```

The only problem with this is the response returns like this:

```
<s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <SearchResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <SearchResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:RecordInfo>
          <a:MyResponse.RecordInf>
            <a:Prop10>Yes</a:Prop10>
            <a:Prop6>
              <a:MyResponse.MyList>
                <a:Prop11>Blah</a:Prop11>
              </a:MyResponse.MyList>
            </a:Prop6>
            <a:Prop5>9780800720957</a:Prop5>
            <a:Prop8>pb</a:Prop8>
            <a:Prop9>9.45</a:Prop9>
            <a:Prop7>Blah</a:Prop7>
            <a:Prop4>Blah</a:Prop4>
          </a:MyResponse.RecordInf>
        </a:RecordInfo>
        <a:SearchResult>
          <a:Prop3 i:nil="true" />
          <a:Prop2>1</a:Prop2>
          <a:Prop1>1</a:Prop1>
        </a:SearchResult>
      </SearchResult>
    </SearchResponse>
  </s:Body>
```

As you can see from the above just after a:RecordInfo it puts the class - a:MyResponse.RecordInf which I don't want. How do I set this up correctly so the XML does not nest in the class name there?

Comment: I removed <DataContract()> above the class names but it didn't change anything in the XML output.

Comment: So what is your desired xml output?

Comment: I don't want the parts that have a:Myresponse before the class name.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way? Just wondering if you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: Still trying to unravel your answer - can you see what I put below it please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have declared RecordInfo as a list of RecordInf objects, so potentialy there may be several objects in list, and WCF needs opening and closing  tag to distinguish one record from another. Otherwise, all properties from all records would be under same tag.

If your RecordInfo always contains just one record - replace list with single RecordInf structure.

Comment: Yes there could be more than one record info. I just don't want the tags with the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default (and normal) behaviour of the `DataContractSerializer` on properties of a collection type (which a `List` is). As per documentation ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx)):

> **Customizing the Repeating Element Name in List Collections**
>
> List collections contain repeating entries. Normally, each repeating
>   entry is represented as an element named according to the data
>   contract name of the type contained in the collection.
>
> In the CustomerList examples, the collections contained strings. The
>   data contract name for the string primitive type is "string", so the
>   repeating element was `&lt;string&gt;`.

You can also change this behaviour. You will have to change your DataContract a little however. You have to introduce your own list type (`Inherits List(Of T)`) and then you can annotate this new list type with a [`CollectionDataContract` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx), in which you can set the `ItemName` to control how the list is being serialized.

Following list class definition will do the trick for you. Just change the `RecordInfo` in your `MyResponse` class to the type `RecordInfList`.

```
<CollectionDataContract(ItemName:="RecordInf")>
Class RecordInfList
    Inherits List(Of RecordInf)
End Class
```

**Please be aware**, for following remark from the documentation ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx#sectionToggle2)):

> **Customizing Collection Types**
>
> You can customize collection types by using the
>   `CollectionDataContractAttribute` attribute, which has several uses.
>
> Note that customizing collection types compromises collection
>   interchangeability, so it is generally recommended to avoid applying
>   this attribute whenever possible. For more information about this
>   issue, see the "Advanced Collection Rules" section later in this
>   topic.

Comment: Thanks for this but I have probably coded it wrong. I am getting this error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyService.MyResponse+RecordInf]' to type 'RecordInfList'.

I changed to the following line of code:

    Public Property RecordInfo() As RecordInfList

And added the CollectionDataContract code snippet you put up there.

Comment: @user3715441 You have to change the initialisation of the property too. You probably have now somewhere in your code `x.RecordInf = New List(Of RecordInf)`. Change it to `x.RecordInfo = New RecordInfList()` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, that *almost* solved it! But now I am getting this:

'<a:RecordInfo>
          <a:RecordInf>'

So within RecordInfo will be a list of RecordInf. But I want *just* a list of RecordInfo. So one RecordInfo after another.

Comment: This is entirely normal. `<a:RecordInfo>` is the property, and each `<a:RecordInf>` item is an element of the list (in that property).

Comment: Yeah, that's not what they're expecting though. Not sure what they're expecting is possible...

Comment: Please update your answer with the expected XML. Otherwise it is only guessing what has to happen.